# DISTINCT ON(Postgres) vs QUALIFY(Snowflake)

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to use the QUALIFY Clause in Snowflake since it does not support the use of DISTINCT ON as Postgres does. However, when I use the QUALIFY Clause in my query it returns different results from that in Postgres, and each time I run this snowflake for a result set of thousands of records it returns a different answer while if I run it for a few hundreds of records it provides the correct result each time. While in Postgres it returns the correct result each time regardless of the size of the result set. According to these pages:

[Using `DISTINCT ON` in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60206664/using-distinct-on-in-snowflake)

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008NrIYuSAN/whats-the-equivalent-of-distinct-on-in-snowflake-

DISTINCT ON and QUALIFY should work in the same way, so I'm not exactly sure why I am having different results?

Snowflake:

```
SELECT wallet_transaction.walletId,
       wallet_transaction.balance,
       wallet_transaction.transactionDate,
       wallet_transaction.parkerId,
       wallet_transaction.operatorName,
       wallet_transaction.operatorId,
       wallet_transaction.offerName,
       wallet_transaction.offerId
FROM wallet_transaction
WHERE {% condition snapshot_date %} wallet_transaction.transactionDate {% endcondition %}
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY wallet_transaction.walletId
ORDER BY wallet_transaction.walletId, wallet_transaction.transactionDate DESC) = 1;
```

Postgres:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(wallet_transaction.walletId)
       wallet_transaction.walletId,
       wallet_transaction.balance,
       wallet_transaction.transactionDate,
       wallet_transaction.parkerId,
       wallet_transaction.operatorName,
       wallet_transaction.operatorId,
       wallet_transaction.offerName,
       wallet_transaction.offerId
FROM wallet_transaction
WHERE {% condition snapshot_date %} wallet_transaction.transactionDate {% endcondition %}
ORDER BY wallet_transaction.walletId,wallet_transaction.transactionDate DESC;
```

Comment: I would write the results to a table and then really examine them to make sure you aren't seeing the preview() just showing different results because of the way the data is stored, or cacheing or something like that. Or..  ORDER the results in a specific way so the preview() is the same

Comment: How is `wallet_transaction.transactionDate` defined *exactly*? Can it be NULL? Can there be duplicates per `walletId`?

Answer (score 1):

`wallet_transaction.walletId`is redundant in the `ORDER BY` clause of `row_number()`, but that cannot explain your observation.

Also assuming your opaque `WHERE` condition isn't broken somehow.

**Duplicates** per `(walletId, transactionDate)` could explain it. Then the result is arbitrary and can change between executions without changes to the table. Postgres typically picks the first row in physical sort order from duplicates. Snowflake has a completely different storage architecture and may arrive at a different pick.

This can even happen with a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(walletId, transactionDate)` if `transactionDate` can be `NULL`, as `NULL` compares distinct for the purpose of a `UNIQUE` constraint (as per SQL standard). See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)

**If** so, add more `ORDER BY` expressions to make the sort order **deterministic**. The PK column of the table would do it - assuming `transaction_id` for lack of declaration. Then you get the row with the smallest `transaction_id` in case of duplicates. Works for Postgres and Snowflake alike.

Snowflake:

```
SELECT walletId
     , balance
     , transactionDate
     , parkerId
     , operatorName
     , operatorId
     , offerName
     , offerId
FROM   wallet_transaction w
WHERE  {% condition snapshot_date %} transactionDate {% endcondition %}
QUALIFY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY walletId
                           ORDER BY transactionDate DESC, transaction_id) = 1;
```

Postgres:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (walletId)
       walletId
     , balance
     , transactionDate
     , parkerId
     , operatorName
     , operatorId
     , offerName
     , offerId
FROM   wallet_transaction w
WHERE  {% condition snapshot_date %} transactionDate {% endcondition %}
ORDER  BY walletId, transactionDate DESC, transaction_id;
```

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY wallet_transaction.walletId ORDER BY wallet_transaction.walletId, wallet_transaction.transactionDate DESC)`  does not make sense for column  `wallet_transaction.walletId` being present on both PARTITION BY and ORDER BY.

```
SELECT
    wallet_transaction.walletId,
    wallet_transaction.balance,
    wallet_transaction.transactionDate,
    wallet_transaction.parkerId,
    wallet_transaction.operatorName,
    wallet_transaction.operatorId,
    wallet_transaction.offerName,
    wallet_transaction.offerId
FROM wallet_transaction
WHERE {% condition snapshot_date %} wallet_transaction.transactionDate {% endcondition %}
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY wallet_transaction.walletId
       ORDER BY wallet_transaction.transactionDate DESC) = 1;
```

It means that column `wallet_transaction.transactionDate` alone does not provide **stable sort**.

---

It could be confirmed by checking windowed `COUNT` partitioned by all columns present on PARTITION and ORDER BY clauses:

```
SELECT
    wallet_transaction.walletId,
    wallet_transaction.balance,
    wallet_transaction.transactionDate,
    wallet_transaction.parkerId,
    wallet_transaction.operatorName,
    wallet_transaction.operatorId,
    wallet_transaction.offerName,
    wallet_transaction.offerId
FROM wallet_transaction
WHERE {% condition snapshot_date %} wallet_transaction.transactionDate {% endcondition %}
QUALIFY COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY wallet_transaction.walletId,
                      wallet_transaction.transactionDate DESC) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing nondeterministic conditions of a sort order. For example, if you have a table with 3 columns A, B, C. If A is the ID and B has duplicates for a given Id, if you take the first value of a query partitioned on A and order by B then column C will have different values for each run because of the duplicate in the ordering column (B).